# Azure SWA: redirect to modified version of requested route?

Tags: azure, authentication, redirect, routes, azure-static-web-app

I set up a site using Azure Static Web Apps. I have two use cases I haven't been able to solve nicely for, and I think the same functionality might address both:

- When a user is not authenticated, they're redirected to `<my-site>/.auth/login/<my-auth-provider>`. But, that means when they're brought back after logging in, they go to `/index.html`, which is not ideal. Most of the traffic to this site will be to specific leaf pages. **I'd like to redirect to `<my-site>/.auth/login/<my-auth-provider>?fromUrl=<the-requested-url>` instead, if possible.**
- When a user requests a "pretty" url address e.g. `<my-site>/pretty-url`, I noticed that Azure SWA doesn't handle that the normal way, rewriting to `<my-site>/pretty-url/index.html`. **I'd like it to at least *try* to rewrite to `<my-site>/pretty-url/index.html`.**

Answer (score 2):

It is now possible to redirect back to the referrer after authenticating by configuring a response override in the `staticwebapp.config.json`.

```json
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "allowedRoles": [
        "authenticated"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "responseOverrides": {
    "401": {
      "statusCode": 302,
      "redirect": "/.auth/login/github?post_login_redirect_uri=.referrer"
    }
  }
}
```

You will need to append `?post_login_redirect_uri=.referrer` to the authentication URL of your IDP.

- [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization#set-up-post-sign-in-redirect)
- [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/502#issuecomment-960461443)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like neither of these are possible at the moment.

Here's [a Github issue about redirecting after login](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/502), and one about [enforcing trailing slashes](https://github.com/Azure/static-web-apps/issues/42).